# SqlException: Invalid object name Person.Person

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, database-schema, datacontext, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-database-context-1) tutorial to create a sample API in AspNet Core 3.1 using Visual Studio 2019 project templates, but since I'm using the AdventureWorks (2019) database, I've had to make some changes.

Database Context has been *scaffolded* like this.

```
public partial class AdventureWorks2019Context : DbContext
{
   public AdventureWorks2019Context(){}

   public AdventureWorks2019Context(DbContextOptions<AdventureWorks2019Context> options)
            : base(options){}
   .
   .
   .
   public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

And then I have registered this context in **startup.cs** like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<AdventureWorks2019Context>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

I have also *scaffolded* a People controller, but when I try GetPerson() method it doesn't work, I get a **"SqlException: Invalid object name 'Person.Person'"** error message.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Person>>> GetPerson()
   {
     return await _context.Person.ToListAsync(); //==> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Person.Person'.
   }
```

And that's the error **SqlException: Invalid object name 'Person.Person'.**
But when I do it like this (below), it works. But, I don't want to do it this way because I would be missing the whole point of Dependency Injection, the way I see it.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Person>>> GetPerson()
{
    AdventureWorks2019Context awc = new AdventureWorks2019Context();
    return await awc.Person.ToListAsync();//==> Works fine
}
```

In either case, what gets sent to the SQL Server is this, which works fine.

```
SELECT [p].[BusinessEntityID], 
[p].[AdditionalContactInfo], 
[p].[Demographics], 
[p].[EmailPromotion], 
[p].[FirstName], 
[p].[LastName], 
[p].[MiddleName], 
[p].[ModifiedDate], 
[p].[NameStyle], 
[p].[PersonType], 
[p].[rowguid], 
[p].[Suffix], 
[p].[Title]
FROM [Person].[Person] AS [p]
```

I just don't know where this error is coming from.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure that the table name in your database matches the table name you defined.

Comment: What is  `[Person].[Person]`,What is the structure of this table?

Comment: The first [Person] refers to the database schema, and the second is the table. 
[Schema].[Table] ==> [Person].[Person]

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the issue was I was dealing with two different connection strings.

The scaffolded data context was using a hardcoded connection string, which was ok, so it worked when I created the context manually, instead of injecting it.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=cougar-one\\dev01;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2019;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}
```

But, when I went on to register it on **StartUp.cs**, I used a connection string named "**DefaultConnection**", which was pointing to a totally different database.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<AdventureWorks2019Context>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

So that's why the injected context didn't work.

Comment: The DbContextOptions can be supplied to the DbContext by overriding the OnConfiguring method or externally via a constructor argument.
If both are used, OnConfiguring is applied last and can overwrite options supplied to the constructor argument.

Comment: This is not provided in your code, but I am glad you can solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, I've learned that the hard way. Thank you.